# Class Google_Service not found on Calendar.php line 32

Tags: php, api, calendar

I'm trying to create a simple php form that inserts event to google calendar with the use of google-api-php

but I always encounter this error

**Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\gcalphp\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Service\Calendar.php on line 32**

can someone point to the right direction? I've been searching for the solution for ages. the Documentation from google isn't any of help

here's the snippet

```
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php";
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setUseObjects(true);
$client->setApplicationName("your-app-name");
$client->setClientId("######1hg3nkk4cp28.apps.googleusercontent.com");
$client->setAssertionCredentials(
    new Google_AssertionCredentials(
        "######php@gcalproject-1230.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        array(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
        ),
        file_get_contents("certificates/gcalproject-2cb78099d23a.p12")
    )
);

$service = new Google_CalendarService($client);

$event = new Google_Event();
$event->setSummary('Event 1');
$event->setLocation('Somewhere');
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2016-02-22T19:00:00.000+01:00');
$start->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2016-02-22T19:25:00.000+01:00');
$end->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
$event->setEnd($end);

$calendar_id = "#####bd@group.calendar.google.com";

$new_event = null;

try {
    $new_event = $service->events->insert($calendar_id, $event);
    //
    $new_event_id= $new_event->getId();
} catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    syslog(LOG_ERR, $e->getMessage());
}

$event = $service->events->get($calendar_id, $new_event->getId());
//
if ($event != null) {
    echo "Inserted:";
    echo "EventID=".$event->getId();
    echo "Summary=".$event->getSummary();
    echo "Status=".$event->getStatus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same issue.
Found that you are using the old API language, instead of the new.
Use '**Google_Service_Calendar**' instead of '**Google_CalendarService**'

I am still looking for the new naming for '**Google_EventDateTime**' and will keep you posted
W

Comment: 'Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime' this function it worked for me.